# Firestore - How to create a composite index on all entries of the map?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an android query:

```
Query query = firestore
    .collection("users")
    .orderBy("email")
    .whereEqualTo("packages." + pkg, true);
```

So I need to create a composite index including email and packages.`Package Name`.

But the problem is I need to create a new index every time I create a new Package.

How can I index over a complete map, So that it will automatically add an index on every entry in the package map and email?

I tried adding:

```
field 1 - email - Ascending
field 2 - packages - Ascending
```

But it didn't work

Is regex possible, like:

```
field 1 - email - Ascending
field 2 - packages.`.*`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using map where the properties of the map are essentially unbounded and require lots of indexes, you should instead use a list field for this query.  If you take the package strings and put them into list like this:

```
packages: (list)
  0: package1
  1: package2
```

You can query for existence of a package in that field like this using an [array membership query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership):

```
Query query = firestore
    .collection("users")
    .orderBy("email")
    .whereArrayContains("packages", pkg);
```

Comment: Yes, this is good suggestion, but unfortunately it can't work for me. I already have two many documents in collection and application already deployed which uses maps. Is there something else which can help me. May be I can update using firebase function.

Comment: No, you won't be able to use your map-based solution without creating indexes for each package.  You are limited to 200 of them. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#indexes